# Relation between connected sets and limit point

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I'm studing topology by Munkres book and I am intrigued with two results:

> Lemma 23.1 If $Y$ is a subspace of $X$, a separation of $Y$ is a pair of disjoint nonempty sets $A$ and $B$ whose union is $Y$, neither of whitch **contains a limit point of the other**. The space $Y$ is connected if there exists no separation of $Y$.
>
> Theorem 23.4. Let $A$ be a connected subspace of $X$. If $A \subset B \subset \overline{A}$, then $B$ is also connected.
>
> Said differently: If $B$ is formed by adjoining to the connected subspace $A$ **some or all of its limit points**, then $B$ is connected.

So, my question is: what's the interpetration or intuitive meaning and relation between limits point and connected spaces?

In their proofs, this conditions of limit points seems to me to be just a "technical condition". I try to look for some interpretation for these two results, but I can't come up with anything "palpable".

In the example 2. The subset $Y = [-1,0) \cup (0,1]$ of the real line $\mathbb{R}$, $[-1,0) $ and $(0,1]$ are open subsets of $Y$ and they form a separation of $Y$. In the standard topology of $\mathbb{R}$, $0$ is a limit point of booth sets, but neither of these sets contains $0$. If I "add" 0 in some of these sets, for example ${0} \cup (0,1]$ then, $[-1,0) \cup [0,1]$ is not equal to $Y$, therefore, is not a separation of $Y$.

Comment: I know a definition for a disconnected _space_ $X$ where a separation is a pair of _open_ subsets $X_1$ and $X_2$ such that    $X_1 \cup X_2 = X$ and $X_1 \cap X_2 = \emptyset$. I see two differences with your definition, where $Y$ is a subset and $A$ and $B$ are not required to be open. Adding the condition about limit points prevents $[0, 1/2)$ and $[1/2, 1]$ from being a separation of the connected subset of $[0,1]$ of $\mathbb{R}$. It would be interesting to prove the equivalence of the two definitions, though.

Comment: I think the intuition would be to think of a limit points $x \in X$ as point in your topological space, which can be approximated. So, if $A$ contains a limit point $x$ of $B$, then it would mean, we can somehow approximate $x$ by points of $B$. 

The proof for equivalence of the two definitions should straight forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A separation of a topological *space* $Y$ is a pair of two disjoint *open* subsets $A$ and $B$ such that $A \cup B = Y$ and $A \cap B = \emptyset$. If a separation exists, $Y$ is disconnected.

We can prove the equivalence of this definition of separation with the one you reported in the lemma in the following way.

A subset $Y$ of a topological space $X$ can be regarded as a *space* itself, with the subset topology inherited by $X$. A subset $S \in Y$ is open in $Y$ if there exists an open set $P \in X$ and $S = P \cap Y$.

Let's take a pair of two disjoint non empty subsets $A$ and $B$ such that $A \cup B = Y$ neither of which contains an accumulation point of the other. An accumulation point $p \in X$ of $A$ is a point $p \notin A$ such that for each open  subset $V \in X$ we have $A \cap V \neq \emptyset$. As $B$ does not contain accumulation points of $A$, for each $b \in B$ there exists an open subset $V_b \in X$ which does not contain points of $A$. The union $\bigcup\limits_{b \in B} V_b$ is an open subset of $X$ and $B$ is a subset of $Y$ such that $ B = \bigcup\limits_{b \in B} V_b \cap Y$, hence $B$ is *open* in $Y$. Similarly, $A= \bigcup\limits_{a \in A} V_a \cap Y$ is open in $Y$, hence $Y$ as a *space* has a separation in two sets $A$ and $B$ that are *open* under the subset topology.

Conversely, if $A$ and $B$ are open in $Y$  and form a separation of $Y$, it means that for each $a \in A$ there exists an open subset of $Y$ $V_a \subset A$. As $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, for each $a \in A$ $a$ is not an accumulation point of $B$. Same for $A$.

I am not sure why $Y$ is indicated as a subset and not a space itself, but I think all I wrote above holds if we consider $Y$ as a space itself, without resorting to the subset topology. Note that $A$ and $B$ can be either regarded as subsets of $X$ or of $Y$.

Informally, if $A$ does not have accumulation points of $B$ means that all its points are "internal" ($B$ is the complement of $A$) hence it is an open set .

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thx!!I appreciate your answer

Comment: @Zaratustra is there anything else in your question that you wanted to clarify?